# button can't advance to another view if

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want that when the user puts a number in a textfield this number will be used for lots of operations, but this number can't be 0, i created a error message that will be displayed if user clicks on the "next" button whit a 0 on the textfield, but this message don't have time to appear, because this button takes the user to another view, how do i tell the button to stay in that view until the number is ok? my button implementation:

```
- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender {  

    int mynumber;
    mynumber = [textfieldnumber.text intValue];

    if (mynumber==0) {

        NSString *errorstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Please, set the number of people..."];
        labelerror.text = errorstr;


    }


}
```

Comment: How does the button take the user to another view?  Are you using a storyboard?  Do you have a segue attached to the button?

Comment: the button takes the user using modal. Yes, storyboard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Segue from Storyboards. Then make a new one that goes from file owner, or the little yellow box at the bottom of a selected view to the new modalViewController. Set it's identifier and remember it. Then change this:

```
- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender {  

int mynumber;
mynumber = [textfieldnumber.text intValue];

if (mynumber==0) {

    NSString *errorstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Please, set the number of people..."];
    labelerror.text = errorstr;


}


}
```

to this:

```
- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender {  

int mynumber;
mynumber = [textfieldnumber.text intValue];

if (mynumber==0) {

    NSString *errorstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Please, set the number of people..."];
    labelerror.text = errorstr;


}else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifies sender:self];

}

}
```

or

```
- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender {  

int mynumber;
mynumber = [textfieldnumber.text intValue];

if (mynumber==0) {

    NSString *errorstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Please, set the number of people..."];
    labelerror.text = errorstr;


}else{
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}


}
```

Comment: i've already identified the segue as "calcsegue" but a error appeared telling that i'm using a undeclared identfier...

Comment: I'm stupid! I'm new with objective-c so i didn't remember to put the name into @""... Thanks, you've really helped me! when i get my 15 rep points, i'll give you a upvote!

Comment: No problem! We've all been new once.